# Pointer pressure is 0 in Safari in pointer events despite button being pressed

Tags: javascript, safari, dom-events, mouseevent

I implemented pointer events on my website. I use the "pressure" property to check if a button is currently pressed. The code goes something like this:

```
let element = document.querySelector("#some_id"),
pointer = function(e) {
  if (e.pressure>0) console.log("ok");
};
element.onpointermove = pointer;
```

When I drag on the #some_id element, Chrome, Firefox, and Edge all show "ok" in the console. But Safari doesn't. I have tested it on two MacBooks (when I use Chrome on a MacBook, everything works fine, so it is not a hardware issue). Why does it happen? How do I check if the button is pressed in Safari?

I tried looking for answers on the Internet but surprisingly "safari pointer down pressure 0" yielded no relevant results. Am I the only person having this issue?

Comment: Maybe Safari reserves pressure for pressure sensitive touch devices only and mouse or regular touchpad always yield pressure 0? Anyway, I think I came up with a workaround: 
if (e.pressure+e.buttons>0) console.log("ok");
seems to work well in all browsers, although it is somewhat ugly and may cause unintended consequences for people using more than one device.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent/pressure) says that *For hardware that does not support pressure, such as a mouse, the value is 0.5 when the pointer is active buttons state and 0 otherwise.*. So I guess that's a bug